TwitchAPI Using the Rate Limit Bucket and Throtteling Queries
How do you track how many queries are left in the rate-limit-bucket for stream-info? I want to slow/pause queries to not exceed the limit. In TwitchAPI, I've found twitchAPI.helper.RateLimitBucket but have no idea how to use it to track stream-information requests.
As I understand, query limits for different requests are: Stream Requests (100?), General Requests (app/user) (800), and JWTs Extension viewer(?): (30). Please correct me if I'm wrong on any of those.
This code queries and waits, but doesn't know how many queries are available in the bucket. I use user-queries instead of stream-queries for ease of example, but care about steam queries.
import time, asyncio, twitchAPI

async def init_api(user, key):
    return await twitchAPI.twitch.Twitch(user, key)


async def get_user_data(api, channel_name):
    return await twitchAPI.helper.first(api.get_users(logins=channel_name))


async def get_stream_data(api, channel_name):
    return await twitchAPI.helper.first(api.get_streams(user_login=channel_name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = 'ABCD'
    key = 'EFGH'
    channel = "test_channel"

    twitch_api = asyncio.run(init_api(user, key))
    while True:
        stream_dict = asyncio.run(get_user_data(twitch_api, channel)).__dict__
        print("Stream Data:", stream_dict)
        time.sleep(5)

